# WPF: How to descale linethickness in only one axis

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scaletransform, rendertransform

In WPF I am trying to draw graph lines in a UserControl.  I will need to scale the X and Y values by different amounts.

I have a sample project I will include below.  The problem is that when I use RenderTransform to scale the graph line, the LineThickness is also scaled.  This would normally not be a problem because I could descale the line thickness by the inverse of the scaled value:
  LineThickness = desiredLineThickness * (1/scaledValue)

Unfortunately, in this application I will need to scale the X and Y dimensions by very different values, and LineThickness is not separated into X and Y values.

In my example below I am drawing a sine wave that is scaled to the size of the drawing surface of the user control.  You can see that the peaks and valleys extend beyond the drawing surface.  This is because the original data goes from 1.0 to -1.0 and is scaled to the height of the drawing surface and translated to the middle of the drawing surface.

To demonstrate it more clearly, I also draw a blue line from 0,0 to 90,90 and then from 90,90 horizontally to the right.  This line is also scaled to the height of the drawing surface.  You can see the horizontal line is very thick.

I need a way to descale these lines in the Y axis separately from the X axis which is not scaled in this case.

I have tried several approaches including making a contained object of lines.  I was thinking I could put the endpoints of the lines in the scaled position and then when drawing the actual lines, I would use a render transform to descale the Y values, but I could never get that to work because of the whole binding proxy problem.

Anyone have any ideas or have been faced with this before?  I can't be the first with this problem.

Here is the code:

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        #region Constructor

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GraphPens = new ObservableCollection<GraphPen>();
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Public Methods

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Pens

        public static PropertyMetadata GraphPenMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty GraphPensProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "GraphPens",
                typeof(ObservableCollection<GraphPen>),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                GraphPenMetadata);

        public ObservableCollection<GraphPen> GraphPens
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<GraphPen>)GetValue(GraphPensProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GraphPensProperty, value); }
        }

        // Debug Text

        public static PropertyMetadata DebugTextMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty DebugTextProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "DebugText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                DebugTextMetadata);

        public string DebugText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DebugTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DebugTextProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties

        private void DrawingSurface_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GraphPen graphPen in GraphPens)
            {
                graphPen.SetDrawingDimensions(e.NewSize.Height, e.NewSize.Width);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl Name="ExampleControl"
             x:Class="WpfExampleControlLibrary.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExampleControlLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <local:BindingProxy
            x:Key="UserControlBindingProxy"
            Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GraphPen}">
            <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <ScaleTransform
                                            CenterX="0.0"
                                            CenterY="0.0"
                                            ScaleX="1.0"
                                            ScaleY="{Binding ScaleHeight}"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform 
                                            X="0.0"
                                            Y="{Binding TranslateHeight}"/>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <Path
                            Data="{Binding PenGeometry}"
                            StrokeThickness="{Binding PenLineThickness}"
                            Stroke="{Binding
                                PenLineColor,
                                PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=None}"
                            />
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="DrawingSurface" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" SizeChanged="DrawingSurface_SizeChanged">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Aquamarine">
                        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
                        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer
                        Collection="{Binding
                            Source={StaticResource UserControlBindingProxy}, 
                            Path=Data.GraphPens,
                            Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Line X1="10" Y1="0" X2="200" Y2="180" Stroke="DarkRed" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="debug"
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding
                Source={StaticResource UserControlBindingProxy},
                Path=Data.DebugText,
                Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

GraphPen.cs:

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    public class GraphPen : DependencyObject
    {
        private double _drawingSurfaceHeight = 100;

        #region Constructor

        public GraphPen()
        {
            PenGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            PenGeometry.Figures.Add(new PathFigure());
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Dependency Properties

        // LineColor

        public static PropertyMetadata PenLineColorPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenLineColorProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenLineColor",
                typeof(Brush),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenLineColorPropertyMetadata);
        public Brush PenLineColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(PenLineColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenLineColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // LineThickness

        public static PropertyMetadata PenLineThicknessPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenLineThicknessProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenLineThickness",
                typeof(Int32),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenLineThicknessPropertyMetadata);
        public Int32 PenLineThickness
        {
            get { return (Int32)GetValue(PenLineThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenLineThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        // PenYMin

        public static PropertyMetadata PenYMinPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenYMinProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenYMin",
                typeof(Double),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenYMinPropertyMetadata);
        public double PenYMin
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(PenYMinProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenYMinProperty, value); }
        }

        // PenYMax

        public static PropertyMetadata PenYMaxPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenYMaxProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenYMax",
                typeof(Double),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenYMaxPropertyMetadata);
        public double PenYMax
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(PenYMaxProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenYMaxProperty, value); }
        }

        // ScaleHeight

        public static PropertyMetadata ScaleHeightPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty ScaleHeightProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ScaleHeight",
                typeof(Double),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                ScaleHeightPropertyMetadata);
        public double ScaleHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScaleHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        // TranslateHeight

        public static PropertyMetadata TranslateHeightPropertyMetadata
            = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty TranslateHeightProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "TranslateHeight",
                typeof(Double),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                TranslateHeightPropertyMetadata);
        public double TranslateHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TranslateHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TranslateHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        // Pen Geometry

        public static PropertyMetadata PenGeometryMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static DependencyProperty PenGeometryProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "PenGeometry",
                typeof(PathGeometry),
                typeof(GraphPen),
                PenGeometryMetadata);

        public PathGeometry PenGeometry
        {
            get { return (PathGeometry)GetValue(PenGeometryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PenGeometryProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties

        public void SetDrawingDimensions(double height, double width)
        {
            double dataHeight;

            _drawingSurfaceHeight = height;

            dataHeight = PenYMax - PenYMin;
            ScaleHeight = _drawingSurfaceHeight / dataHeight;
            TranslateHeight = ScaleHeight * -PenYMin;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="POC_WPF_UserControlExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Exmpl="clr-namespace:WpfExampleControlLibrary;assembly=WpfExampleControlLibrary"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POC_WPF_UserControlExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="550">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Exmpl:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myExample"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace POC_WPF_UserControlExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _timer = null;
        private GraphPen _graphPen0 = null;
        private GraphPen _graphPen1 = null;
        private Int32 _pos = 0;
        private bool _firstTime = true;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _graphPen0 = new GraphPen();
            _graphPen0.PenLineColor = Brushes.DarkGoldenrod;
            _graphPen0.PenLineThickness = 1;
            _graphPen0.PenYMax = 1.0;
            _graphPen0.PenYMin = -1.0;
            myExample.GraphPens.Add(_graphPen0);

            _graphPen1 = new GraphPen();
            _graphPen1.PenLineColor = Brushes.DarkBlue;
            _graphPen1.PenLineThickness = 1;
            _graphPen1.PenYMax = 10.0;
            _graphPen1.PenYMin = 0.0;
            myExample.GraphPens.Add(_graphPen1);

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _pos++;
            Point penPoint0 = new Point(_pos, Math.Sin(_pos % 360));
            Point penPoint1 = new Point(0,0);
            if (_pos <= 9) penPoint1 = new Point(_pos, _pos);
            if (_pos > 9) penPoint1 = new Point(_pos, 9);
            if (_firstTime)
            {
                myExample.GraphPens[0].PenGeometry.Figures[0].StartPoint = penPoint0;
                myExample.GraphPens[1].PenGeometry.Figures[0].StartPoint = penPoint1;
                _firstTime = false;
            }
            else
            {
                LineSegment segment0 = new LineSegment(penPoint0, true);
                myExample.GraphPens[0].PenGeometry.Figures[0].Segments.Add(segment0);
                LineSegment segment1 = new LineSegment(penPoint1, true);
                myExample.GraphPens[1].PenGeometry.Figures[0].Segments.Add(segment1);
            }

            myExample.DebugText = _pos.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT by poster**

I forgot to show BindingProcy.cs

```
namespace WpfExampleControlLibrary
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Override Freezable Abstract Parts
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion Override Freezable Abstract Parts

        #region Dependency Properties

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.
        // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static PropertyMetadata DataMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Data",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(BindingProxy),
                DataMetadata);

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

**EDIT by poster**

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to ask a more generalized question in simple language.

Comment: "The problem is that when I use RenderTransform ...". Actually, the problem is that you use RenderTransform in the first place. Better use the Transform property of a Geometry in the Data property of a Path control.